# Understanding method signature syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

When I read MDN docs like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and see

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
```

What kind of syntax are they using? Where can I find more info on it, as it's unclear to me what it's saying.

Answer (score 1):

They are indicating that the function accepts an arbitrary number of arguments via an [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Arguments in square brackets are optional; they are indicating that each optional argument may have a subsequent optional argument, up to an indefinite number of arguments.

Comment: where can I find more info on this syntax?

Comment: That is a [convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) used for years, started in times when UNIX ruled the Earth.

Comment: you know now that i think of it you didn't actually answer the question. what i meant is where is the notation from?